# A simple sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named attribute:

```
id attributeid type
1         8      2
2         8      1
3         4      1
```

So how can I select attributeid that have both types of 2 and 1. In this case, only attribute 8 is qualified that.

```
select attributeid 
from attribute
where type in (1,2)
```

This doesn't produce the results I want, as it returns 4,8 which is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you normalized your table right.

Comment: Wich RDMBS, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre? Please retag your question to get answers that best fits your problem.

Comment: i think with simple statement like this RDMBS is not a big problem. anyway, i'm using MSSQL server

Comment: Is not about if your query is simple or not. Is about writing better questions, get better answers and let others find it easily. Check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast). There is more but these links should help you to understand why the need of correct tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select t1.attributeid
from yourtable t1
where type = 1 
  and exists (select type
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.attributeid = t2.attributeid
                and t2.type = 2)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bfca/1)

Answer (score 3):

Provided that there can't be multiple rows with the same `type` value for the same `attributeid`, I think something like this is appropriate:

```
select attributeid
from attribute
where type in (1,2)
group by attributeid
having COUNT(*) = 2
```

Which is effectively asking whether the query (without the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`) produced two rows for the same `attributeid`. This is then easy to extend if you add another type value:

```
select attributeid
from attribute
where type in (1,2,6)
group by attributeid
having COUNT(*) = 3
```

And is generally referred to as relational division.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that in future you have a row like these :

```
id attributeid type
1         8      3
1         8      4
```

Then will you be again changing your query to satisfy this conditon also ??? 
 like

`where type in(1,2,3,4)`

To make it a universal query, you can try

```
select attributeid 
from attribute
where type in (select unique(type) from attribute)
group by attributeid 
having COUNT(*) = (select count(unique(type)) from attribute);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is named `attribute`, then each attribute should occur only once. Shouldn't it be named `attributetype` or something?

Anyway:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Attribute t
where
  exists (
    select * from Attribute t1 
    where t1.AttributeId = t.AttributeId and t1.Type = 1) and
  exists (
    select * from Attribute t1 
    where t1.AttributeId = t.AttributeId and t1.Type = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
SELECT A.attributeid
FROM Table A
WHERE type = 1 
AND EXISTS (SELECT  type FROM Table B WHERE A.attributeid = B.attributeid AND B.type = 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

what about maybe something more like :

select attributeid from attribute
where (type = 1) and (type = 2)

Comment: Wild guess? Have you actually seen the table in the question?